# channels_presence.models.Presence runtimeError

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

its my first time implementing a Websockets with Django and I'm struggling to do this.

I keep getting this error everytime I try to runserver: `RuntimeError: Model class channels_presence.models.Presence doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'votemanager',
'roommanager',
'rest_framework',
'multiselectfield',
'django_filters',
'channels',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you're note using `django-channels-presence` then can you remove it? I don't see `channel_presence` declared in the INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Thanks @RajaSimon! I forgot to add the "channel_presence" to INSTALLED_APPS and after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add `channel_presense` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` so that Django will recognise   channel_present app and then you can use the `channels_presence.models.Presence`